# Google Adwords Incorrect statistics

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm using the Google AdWords PHP API to access statistics from our account. However, I'm getting some really strange read outs from the statistics through the api. I'm trying to access the stats for individuals Ads or Adgroups. The statistics returned, however, are way off what they are in the client center. The code I'm using:

```
$user->SetClientCustomerId($clientId);
$adService = $user->GetService("AdGroupAdService", ADWORDS_VERSION);
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array("Id", "Name", "Clicks", "Impressions", "Cost");
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate("AdGroupId", "IN", array($adGroupId));
$selector->dateRange = $dateRange;
$selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);
do {
        // Make the get request.
        $page = $adService->get($selector);

        if (isset($page->entries)) {
                foreach ($page->entries as $ad) {
                     $newLineObject->adName = $ad->name;
                     $newLineObject->clicks = $ad->ad->AdStats->clicks;
                     $newLineObject->impressions = $ad->adStats->impressions;
                     $newLineObject->cost = $ad->ad->AdStats->cost->microAmount/ AdWordsConstants::MICROS_PER_DOLLAR;
                }
        }
        else {
          print "No matching ads were found.\n";
        }
        $selector->paging->startIndex += AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE;

} while ($page->totalNumEntries > $selector->paging->startIndex);
```

When I print the results I get numbers that are considerably larger than those displayed in the client center. For example, for one partiuclar Ad the API reported 2.000.000 impressions, while the client center showed 56.000.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried using the method detailed above extensively, I have altered my code completely. I now use AdHoc Reporting (described here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting). This method was suggested to me by an AdWords developer. While this does not literally solve my question (i.e. why does the above code return incorrect statistics), it does provide an easy and clean way to obtain the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. However, you problem may be that your date range in your code is different to the one you see in your client center. Make sure that you keep the same date range when you cross check.